# Hide Terminated message when killing pipe process

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

I have a bash script like this:

```
{
commands
...
} 2>&1 | tee file.log
```

The problem is that when I kill the script, an error is printed like this:

```
line 214:  8679 Terminated              { commands...} 2>&1
      8680  | tee file.log
```

Is there a way I can prevent this message from showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable and enable job control:

```
set +m
kill ...
set -m
```